# "Fails to create Object" for ActiveX control in VC++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++

Below Method is being executed multiple time for single Object creation, and ultimately fails to create ActiveX control object. Value of HRESULT shows hresult = -2,147,467,262

```
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
      HRESULT hres = _Module.GetClassObject(rclsid, riid, ppv);
      return hres;
}
```

The same method is being executed just once for another ActiveX control and object created successfully with :   hresult = 0;

Any help for probable reasons for failure to create object.

Comment: Please consider "return hres; " included in above method, missed to post.

Comment: The error code is `E_NOINTERFACE`, which means the object corresponding to that `rclsid` does not in fact support the interface requested via `riid`. Figure out why.

Comment: Yes, the mentioned negative HRESULT value translates to 0x80004002 / 
E_NOINTERFACE error code with description "No such interface supported." as per MSDN. But what possibly can cause this, while creating an object of ActiveX control.

Comment: It could be caused by the fact that the object corresponding to that `rclsid` does not in fact support the interface requested via `riid`. Figure out why. A good place to start would be to determine what interfaces are being queried for.

Comment: DllGetClassObject function gets executed two times, rclsid remains same in both execution. Additionally:
In first execution riid = IID_IClassFactory2, ppv = 0x005be5bc, hresult = -2147467262 ;
In second execution: riid = IID_IClassFactory, ppv = 0x005bf2ec, hresult = 0.
Also, I tried to add this ActiveX control to a Dialog of another basic mfc application using mouse right click and "Insert ActiveX control". It gives two errors on trot as:

1. The ActiveX control cannot be instantiated.
2. "Times Control" is not a valid ActiveX control. It is missing a required interface.

Comment: Seems working as intended, then. It is normal and expected for a class factory to not support `IClassFactory2` and to support `IClassFactory`. To the extent there is a problem, it lies elsewhere.

Comment: Adding a line "COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistStreamInit)", under

"BEGIN_COM_MAP(MyControl)-------- END_COM_MAP()"

solved the issue. 
Please help me to understand this with your comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX control that has persistent state, which was the case with this control, must implement either IPersistStream or IPersistStreamInit. 
Adding a line "COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistStreamInit)", under

"BEGIN_COM_MAP(MyControl)-------- END_COM_MAP()"

solved the issue.